# Помогите правильно составить массив для входного слоя нейросети

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras

Я новичок в нейросетях, и не до конца понимаю как нужно составлять массив для входного слоя нейросети. Имею следующий код:

```
def create_lexicon():
      data = open('data/cat_1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8').read()
      labels, lexicon, texts = [], [], []
      for i, line in enumerate(data.split("\n")):
        content = line.split()
        labels.append(content[0])
        texts.append(content[1:])
        lexicon += content[1:]
      return lexicon, labels, texts # функция возращяет словарь 

    lexicon, labels, texts = create_lexicon()


    def get_word_2_index(lexicon):
        word2index = {} # массив индексов
        for i,word in enumerate(lexicon):
            word2index[word] = i # заполнение масива индексов

        return word2index # заполнененый масив индексов


    word2index = get_word_2_index(lexicon)


    total_words = len(lexicon)
    matrix = np.zeros((total_words),dtype=int)

    matrixs_list = []
    for i in texts:
      for word in i:
       matrix[word2index[word]] = 1
      matrixs_list.append(matrix)


    x_train, y_train = matrixs_list, labels

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=len(lexicon)))
    model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='sgd',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

При его выполнении получаю следующею ошибку:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 60 arrays: [array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       ...,
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]]), array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       ...,
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]]), array([[0],
       [0],
   ...
```

Comment: Приведите пример данных для обучения, а еще лучше выложить все данные на какой-нибудь файлообменник...

Comment: текстовый файл подобного вида: 1 заголовок стати. где 1 - номер категории.

Comment: Важно не это, мне нужно узнать как нужно составить входные данные для нейронной сети

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)